# PDO Object: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

```
$queryString = 'SELECT * FROM n8593370.items AND Suburb = :suburb AND Name LIKE \'%:name%\'';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($queryString);
$stmt->bindValue(':suburb', $suburb);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I am getting the above mentioned error can not for the life of my figure out why.

I am certain I only have 2 variables to bind and that I indeed bind both.

When I perform this with each conditional on their own i.e. `WHERE 1 = 1 AND Suburb = :suburb` or `WHERE 1 = 1 AND Name LIKE \'%:name%\'` I do not have any errors.

ALTHOUGH the latter of the two conditionals does not return any results, however when I test it in MySQL Workbench it works as I expect it.

Can anybody shed some light on the issue?

Comment: Remove that `1 = 1` as it doesn't make sense since it's a tautology.

Comment: do an `echo $queryString` before the execute, and comment out the execute, just to see what you are passing.

Comment: The 1 = 1 is there so I can conditionally append the conditionals for the query. But yes I will comment it out for the questions sake :)

Comment: I think u misunderstood. I was asking for you to comment out the `$stmt->execute()`, and to echo out your $queryString to see what is inside it after you did the parameter binding. It's easier to debug that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using placeholder values it's important to leave any and all escaping out of the query. The value itself should be bare, PDO will take care of the escaping for you if you're disciplined about using placeholder values.

Specify it this way:

```
"...name LIKE :name..."
```

Then you bind this way:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':name', "%$name%");
```

Comment: Awesome, helped heaps, the statement is still returning no results for the like even though it does on workbench but at least I am not getting errors.

Comment: What sorts of values of `$name` are you using? Is there any special characters in them?

Comment: I ended up sorting it out just a syntactical issue.